# Transferring form input value to var

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

As the title says, I'm always can't get value from input field. It's always empty(probably the initial state doesn't change on submit). Can somebody point me in the right direction

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';

class FormContainer extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        cityName: '',
    };
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleCityName = this.handleCityName.bind(this);
}

handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const SendForm = {
        cityName: this.state.cityName
    };
    console.log(SendForm);
}

handleCityName(e) {
    this.setState({ cityName: e.target.value });
}

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
            <label>{this.props.label}</label>
            <SearchBar name="CityName" type="text" value={this.state.cityName} placeholder="search" onSubmit={this.handleCityName}/>
            <button type="submit"
                    className=""
                    value='Submit'
                    placeholder="Search" />
        </form>
    );
}
}

 export {FormContainer};
```

Here is search bar component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const SearchBar = (props) => (
    <div>
     <label>{props.label}</label>
     <input name={props.name} type={props.inputType} value={props.cityName}     placeholder={props.placeholder} />
</div>
);

export default SearchBar;
```

EDIT

```
class FormContainer extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        cityName: '',
    };
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleCityName = this.handleCityName.bind(this);
}

handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const SendForm = {
        cityName: this.state.cityName
    };
    console.log(SendForm);
}

handleCityName(e) {
    this.setState({ cityName: e.target.value });
}

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
            <label>{this.props.label}</label>
            <input name="CityName" type="text" value={this.state.cityName} placeholder="search"/>
            <button type="submit"
                    className=""
                    value='Submit'
                    placeholder="Search" />
        </form>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are not updating the `cityName` in `parent component`.

Solution: Pass a `onChange` method from `parent component` like this:

```
<SearchBar name="CityName" type="text" value={this.state.cityName} placeholder="search" onChange={this.handleCityName}/>

handleCityName(value) {
    this.setState({ cityName: value });
}
```

Use this `method` and pass the `value` entered by user back to `parent` like this:

```
<input name={props.name} type={props.inputType} value={props.value} placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={(e)=>props.onChange(e.target.value)}/>
```

Check the working example on `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/wzez3yc1/

Let me know if you need any help in this.

Comment: its working. Thanks but if it's not bother can you explain this part (e)=>props.onChange(e.target.value)

Comment: this is called `arrow function`, `es6 feature`, read the benefits of `arrow functions`, Here i am passing only value to parent not complete event object, u can also write it like this: `onChange={props.onChange}` and in parent component use `e.target.value` to get the `value` like u used in ques.

Comment: `es6 features` are awesome, try to use them at all places :)